# MongoDB - how store/search word tokens?

Tags: mongodb, search, nlp, nosql, full-text-search

I want to store and search human names, which might consist of two tokens and search for one should produce the result. So if you have "Arthur Conan", search for "arthur" would be a hit.

Question: how should I store the normalized name (in addition to original display name)?

- as a string "arthur conan" => query would use a regex (one where " arthur", "arthur" and "arthur " would be a hit)
- or each name part as an element in an array, e.g. `["arthur", "conan"]` => simple `find({firstName: ["arthur"]})`.

Which way is more flexible/efficient? Can I sort the collection by an array-type or would I need the normalized name as one string anyway?

Would the use-case change if I wanted to search a free text (The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog) => "lazy dog" should be a hit, "dog lazy" should be not, or with a lower score...

Comment: we have text indexes, to search complete words(there is also NOT/AND/OR), a text index takes the string field value, and breaks into tokens(words), case doesn't matter, you can use text index it will be very fast also, but it cant do substring match, for example you cant search for  "arth" for this you need regex

Comment: @Takis Thank you, I just looked up on text indexes and they seemed pefect, but then I read "A collection can only have one text search index, but that index can cover multiple fields." - would that limitation make it possible to implement search logic like this? "arthur doyle" => hit, "arthur conan" => no hit, e.g. both first and last name required, but only one token from first name is enough. As for n-grams like "arth", I don't need those

Comment: Text search is not binary - hit/no hit. It's based on lucene which gives relevance score to each document. Roughly - the higher score, the more words matched. The score is available to the pipeline as metadata.  If you prefer to tokenize text yourself - you can index arrays https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-multikey/  Hit will be where one/all strings from query exactly match (no stemming) at least one string in the array.

Comment: @AlexBlex So if I use a text index spanning over two source indexes (firstName and lastName), I cannot prevent "arthur wronglastname" (not matching last name) to produce a result? Because of European data protection it is a requirement that both firstName and lastName must be provided. If not, I will use index array as you suggested...

Comment: no, not with text index alone, but you can use text index for screening, then refine results on the next steps. In your case I wouldn't recommend text search. It will give you a lot of false positive results, e..g. "green" and "greens" will match.